# Common Header for Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to create a common header for my windows phone 8.1 app. The header should be common across all pages. I am new to Windows Phone App Development. Could anybody suggest the best and cleanest way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you plan on having the header common to absolutely *all* pages without excluding any, you can place your control outside of your Frame. That way, it'll persist between page navigations.

First create your header as a UserControl (Project -> Add New Item -> User Control). Then in your `Application.OnLaunched()` override in App.xaml.cs (or wherever you're creating the Frame), replace this line

```
// Place the frame in the current Window
Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
```

with this

```
var grid = new Grid();
grid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 26, 0, 0);  // compensate for status bar
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

var header = new MyHeaderUserControl();
grid.Children.Add(header);

Grid.SetRow(rootFrame, 1);
grid.Children.Add(rootFrame);

Window.Current.Content = grid;
```

Now your header will appear on all pages similar to this:

[image: screenshot]

Some points:

- I've never had to design an app like this before so I don't know what the consequences of going about it this way are. You can no longer assume that `Window.Current.Content` will be a `Frame` (as a lot of code does).
- The XAML designer won't display the header.
- The Frame element seems to automatically compensate for the appearance of the status bar when it is set to `Window.Current.Content` (like usual). I've had to add a top margin of 26px to the root grid so that the header appears underneath the status bar.
- Page transitions are provided by the frame, and since the header is outside of the frame, it will not participate in page transitions.

---

**Option 2**

If you want more flexibility, such as excluding some pages from displaying the header or changing the content of the header to some page-specific data via data binding, then I suggest you do not change the root frame but instead include the header manually in the pages you want.

---

If your app is simple with few pages, then the first option is probably the easiest, however if your app is complex then you might want the latter instead. Personally, I would always choose the latter option, just because I want maximum flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Decided to go with the 2nd approach.